# Business Objects XI Web Intelligence Aggregation Issue (11.5.8.897)

Tags: reporting, business-objects

I've got a multiple tabbed report.  On one tab I have the details listed and on another I have a summary table (cross reference) type of aggregation based on the same dimensions utilized in the detail report.  I've created a calculated field that takes the product of two measures, I've saved this as a variable. When I try to aggregate that variable on the summary report BOWI is not calculating correctly.  Example:

```
QTY * PRICE = LineTotal
2 * 3 = 6
4 * 3 = 12

TotalOrder = $18
```

Calculates correctly on the detail report.

When I put this on the aggregate report it is doing the following:
Sum QTY * Sum Price = Total, in other words it is doing

```
6 * 6 = $36.
```

My totals on the aggregate are highly inflated.  Firstly in what world does that order of precedence make sense?  and secondly how can I tell BOWI to sum the TotalOrders instead of breaking it back up into it's components summing those and then multiplying?

Is it a bug?

Further Information
The detail report is Sectioned by Year, Region, State -> Detail lines
The summary report is dimensioned by Year, Region, State

The (QTY * PRICE) component is saved as a variable and utilized in both places.

Am I missing the secret handshake somewhere when calculated fields/variables can't be aggregated and they need to do so in the Universe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I havent worked with WEBI for a while, I mainly develop DESKI reports, however what you describe sounds similar to the aggregation that occurs in DESKI.  If a measure is set to sum aggregation, then it will add all the measures together that relate to the dimension that is added to the report.

For example, if like my details reports, you have the columns order number, qty, price then the aggregation will sum both qty and price at the order level, which is correct.  However moving to the summary table then this will cause incorrect data.

To remove the aggregation you can change it from SUM to NONE, I cant recall off the top of my head on how to do this in WEBI (if you cant find out I can check my course materials which are work).

Alternatively, it is best to ensure the dimensions on your summary report are suitable for the data presented.

If you need any further information please let me know.

Matt